# docker container not reachable for other ip address

Tags: docker, ubuntu

It seems like i can't reach any of the ports that Docker is exposing.

On machine (192.168.13.59  ubuntu 22.04) i have Apache running without docker. I can reach the website from another local pc (192.168.13.15) ->

So to test why my containers can't be reached:

- stopped apache
- sudo docker run -it --rm -d -p 80:80 --name web nginx
- curl http://localhost:80 on the Ubuntu machine shows the Nginx webserver
- opening the webserver from 192.168.13.15 is not possible

So it seems a problem in my docker configuration (not the firewall, as it's inactive and i can do a curl locally)

Any suggestions?

Comment: Use this command and check whether now you can acces the container throught 192.168.13.15
sudo docker run -it --rm -d -p 192.168.13.15:80:80 --name web nginx

Comment: I get this error message:

docker: Error response from daemon: driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint web (62ee53500384a2557b4ce76e8c52dd323aa5de8afb4a06f808f1d7057fd1c9a4): Error starting userland proxy: listen tcp4 192.168.13.15:80: bind: cannot assign requested address.

Comment: Is the 80 port listening for *? (Can be checked using netstat command)
Another thing to check is if there is any firewall blocking traffic between the hosts on the specific port. (firewall can be in either of the servers or if you are using cloud, then in network configuration level)

Answer (score 0):

If the touble began right after updating to 22.04, you can try this installation guide:

[Guide](https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/ubuntu/)
(Do not forget to reboot or to restart the service)